# Data from MySql displaying multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, forms

This is my sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT comments.comment, users.userid, comments.bpid 
       FROM comments, users ,blogpages
       WHERE comments.user_id = users.user and comments.bpid ='".$blogid."'
       ORDER BY comments.cid;"

$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $comm =$row["comment"]; 
        $commentsuser =$row["userid"];
        $commentbody .= "".$commentsuser."".$comm." ";      
}
```

This is my form and display

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea  name="commentarea"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="COMMENT" >
    <h2><?php echo $commentbody; ?></h2>
</form>
```

but after i enter comment each value is displaying multiple times ?

the comment doesn't show up until i re-enter the page

Comment: Why are you writing an `\n` at the end of each line in the sql string? The string is supposed to be an sql command, not a string to be displayed somewhere.

Comment: you've got 3 tables and have a join condition for only ONE of the three, which means the others are going to be a cross-join.

Comment: Run the query in phpMyAdmin or some tool that will allow you to test a query. THEN LOOK AT THE RESULTS.

Comment: Also, "WHERE comments.user_id = users.user". Did you mean users.userid?

Comment: yes the userid column name is user

Comment: Maybe you made several tests and now your database have multiple lines with the same content

Comment: values in database are corrext and only single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a join condition:

```
SELECT   comments.comment, users.userid, comments.bpid 
FROM     comments, users ,blogpages
WHERE    comments.user_id = users.user AND
         comments.bpid = blogpages.id AND -- Missing in the OP
         comments.bpid ='".$blogid."'
ORDER BY comments.cid;
```

Having said that, implicit joins are deprecated, and you should probably be using an explicit join:

```
SELECT   comments.comment, users.userid, comments.bpid 
FROM     comments
JOIN     users ON comments.user_id = users.user
JOIN     blogpages ON comments.bpid = blogpages.id 
WHERE    comments.bpid ='".$blogid."'
ORDER BY comments.cid;
```

This will also help visualize the join condition you were missing, since in this form its an actual part of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sql you are looking for is something like..

```
SELECT 
    comments.comment, 
    users.userid, 
    comments.bpid
FROM 
    comments, 
    INNER JOIN users ON comments.userId = users.userid,
    INNER JOIN blogpages ON comments.bpid = blogpages.bpid
WHERE
    comments.bpid ='".$blogid."'
ORDER BY 
    comments.cid;
```

Comment: Please replace blogpages.bpid and users.userid with appropriate column names.